# external css relative path not working

Tags: html, css, background-image, loading

My problem seems so easy and basic yet its not working for me. I am trying to use background-image in an external css file which is located in the root folder (the image is directly in the root folder as well), I am using Netbeans. I know the web is littered with solutions to path problems and all the solutions seem simple enough but non are working. here is my css:

```
#label label{
   background-image:url("../search.png");
}
```

I have tried variations to the path by adding ../ or / but it does not load and in the ide i get

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the folder structure

Comment: try "..\search.png"

Comment: But I think this code you provide should be working too.have you tried it in a browser ?

Comment: thank you for taking the time to check it out. It is very frustrating because by all accounts it should be working. I have been doing work-arounds for the longest time because this is not the first time but I got fed up and want to find a solution. btw, i tried a backwards slash as you suggested but still not showing.

Comment: have you tried it on a browser?

Comment: i have, i tried chrome and firefox. I usually check all changes right after i make them. its not there. I added another pic of the html if it could help any

Comment: have you opened dev tools on chrome?

Comment: try: #searchlabel{  background-image:url("../search.png"); }

Comment: in dev tools i see the space for it and it is taking the 60x60 i just set for and it shows that space exactly where it is supposed to bet but its empty and all the css is there. I tried changing to the searchlabel id, still nothing.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115050/discussion-between-cssgeek-and-sammyb123).

Comment: no errors, i just changed the image to another one and it partially showed so that is a step in the right direction. Not sure why the first image was not showing because it worked fine when i tested it as a body background in the index.html file but the other one is working now. thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: For future readers: also make sure your issue is not this one: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/293#issuecomment-886815654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image was not working for this task so I changed to another image and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

http://localhost:8383/wikiViewer/css/search.png <- According to the path, you are trying to retrieve the **png image** from within your **css** folder.

If the png is in a folder named say, `/images` which is also within `/wikiViewer`, then you need to go up one level with `../` and then specify the folder name i.e. `../images` and finally the image name `../images/search.png`

```
#labeldiv label{
   background-image:url("../images/search.png");
}
```

Just imagine you are in the **css folder** and you're navigating to the png image through your folders and that the `../` is the **BACK** button.

---

*Please provide an image showing the **file & folder structure** of your site if you want a more specific solution.*

Comment: That was a really good and logical explanation. I added a screen shot but I have already tried what you mentioned with no luck.

Answer (score -3):

The image is not found in the directory.

And the image should not be kept in css folder.
It should be kept in img or some resource folder.
And then map the address accordingly.